# "Unable to start NATS Server in Go Routine" while testing

Tags: go, testing, nats.io

I'm trying to separate tests to use different NATS servers. (I'm not yet sure it is NATS, but my tests influence each other.)

Doing that works fine when running a single test or testing a single package. Running `go test ./...` on all my packages (as done in CI) I get this error (paths anonymised):

```
panic: Unable to start NATS Server in Go Routine

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/nats-io/gnatsd/test.RunServer(0xc000163400, 0xc000163400)
    ./go/pkg/mod/github.com/nats-io/gnatsd@v1.4.1/test/test.go:66 +0xbd
./lib/msgQueue/nats.NewTestConn(0xc0002adf68, 0x1879e12)
    ./lib/msgQueue/nats/testconn.go:19 +0x80
```

It seems like Go starts goroutines to run tests in them. Both using `TestMain` and `init` in the tests does not solve the problem.

Is it possible to start a server per test without running into the `goroutine` error? Or is there some lightweight, but functioning in-memory replacement?

---

Here some code:

```golang
// +build !build

package myNats

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "github.com/nats-io/gnatsd/server"
    "github.com/nats-io/gnatsd/test"
    gonats "github.com/nats-io/go-nats"
)

type Conn struct {
    db *gonats.Conn
}

func NewTestConn() (conn *Conn, shutdown func()) {
    opts := server.Options{
        Host:   "localhost",
        Port:   53347,
        NoLog:  true,
        NoSigs: true,
    }
    gnatsd := test.RunServer(&opts)
    if gnatsd == nil {
        panic("could not start NATS test server")
    }

    url := fmt.Sprintf("nats://%s:%d", opts.Host, opts.Port)
    conn, err := open(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(errors.Wrap(err, "could not connect to test NATS"))
    }

    return conn, func() {
        conn.close()
        gnatsd.Shutdown()
    }
}

func open(addr string) (*Conn, error) {
    // Connect to NATS
    nc, err := gonats.Connect(addr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "nats not reachable on %s", addr)
    }

    if !nc.IsConnected() {
        errorMsg := fmt.Errorf("could not establish connection to nats-server at: %s", addr)
        return nil, errorMsg
    }

    return &Conn{
        db: nc,
    }, nil
}
```

My goal would be to have a server per test:

```golang
func TestSomeThing(t *testing.T) {
    conn, shutdown := myNats.NewTestConn()
    defer shutdown()

    _ = conn
    // test code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error message:

```
Unable to start NATS Server in Go Routine
```

is misleading. The part about the Go Routine is likely just an implementation detail of how it tries to start the NATS Server. I suspect the server is failing to start because you have hardcoded your port in the options, and because multiple test packages are likely being run in parallel. Only one of your test packages will be able to bind to the port to start the NATS Server, and all others will fail.

The [docs on `go test` flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags) say:

```
-parallel n
    Allow parallel execution of test functions that call t.Parallel.
    The value of this flag is the maximum number of tests to run
    simultaneously; by default, it is set to the value of GOMAXPROCS.
    Note that -parallel only applies within a single test binary.
    The 'go test' command may run tests for different packages
    in parallel as well, according to the setting of the -p flag
    (see 'go help build').
```

Unless you have parallel tests within your given test suites, which I'll assume you don't, the problem may be different packages running in parallel. Following the clue at the end of the above, let's look at build flags:

```
-p n
    the number of programs, such as build commands or
    test binaries, that can be run in parallel.
    The default is the number of CPUs available.
```

This is from the ["Compile packages and dependencies" docs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies). Note you can pass build flags **and** test flags to `go test`:

```
$ go test -h
usage: go test [build/test flags] [packages] [build/test flags & test binary flags]
Run 'go help test' for details.
```

So consider running `go test -p 1 ./...`. Alternatively, pass options to the `RunServer` function that allow multiple of them to happen safely in parallel.

Comment: Added a free port seeking ability to the `NewTestConn` function and that fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It likely already starts a server per test. You cannot run things concurrently without a goroutine. The error doesn't really make any sense - anything in Go must be able to run in a goroutine, and in fact everything *does* run in a goroutine (even `main`), so it's unclear what they're really trying to say here (I would definitely recommend opening a bug report about it as that error message is *terrible*). In the meantime, you can keep `go test` from running concurrently with `-parallel 1` (as indicated in `go help testflag`), which might help.

Comment: The NATS server seems to check if it is running in a Go routine: https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server/blob/master/test/test.go#L84

Comment: About opening a bug report: The nats.io team seems to use Stackoverflow for asking questions... so that is what I did: https://nats.io/contributing/#communityhelp

Comment: Not a question, a bug report. And it can't "check if it is running in a Go routine" - as I indicated in my answer, if such a check were possible it would literally *always* return `true`, because *everything runs in a goroutine*. They're checking something, but I'm not sure what. What the error text says is complete nonsense.

Comment: In this case it seems the error message is indeed bogus. Thx

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I already ran an instance of nats-server so the tests were failing. By stopping the server, tests were passed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add `GODEBUG=x509sha1=1` before `go test` command

P.S. go1.18.3